# Trying to disable layout in zend

Tags: zend-framework, layout

I try to disable layout in zend action in this way:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

But it doesn't work:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Application_Controller_Helper_Layout::disableLayout() in application/controllers/AssetController.php on line 18
```

I reckon that its, because I made my own helper.

Bootsrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initMyActionHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Layout');
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($layout);
    }

}
```

application.ini

```
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Application_Controller_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers/helpers"
```

and my helper

```
class Application_Controller_Helper_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite Zend default layout helper, please extend Zend_Layout_Controller_Action_Helper_Layout.

```
class Application_Controller_Helper_Layout extends Zend_Layout_Controller_Action_Helper_Layout
```

Then you will still be able to use default disableLayout() function if you are not overwriting it in your own helper.

Try testing it using:

```
class Application_Controller_Helper_Layout extends Zend_Layout_Controller_Action_Helper_Layout
{
    public function preDispatch(){}

    public function disableLayout(){
        echo "I won't disable layout anymore, because I overwrote the action with displaying this string.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I just changed the name from Layout to Lay, and everthing works now!

Comment: You are welcome. That will work too. I wasn't sure whether you wanted to keep using that helper name because as I mentioned above it will replace the default one. So for future reference, try to avoid using same name with zend default helpers, if you are not sure, take a search before naming it is the quickest way.